# I want to make a download of a forum

Tags: networking

I moderate, before it closes for good. There's some useful info on it I want to save for myself and I don't want to export the data to another webserver, I just want the pages. Mind you, I'm a user at the forum, not the admin. Now, I googled this and found it can be easily done with wget

Comment: You can use F12 to copy some data, or you can make the pages to be pictures. If just a link, it could be expired.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to download.If its just a page then you can download the forum page as a pdf. You can simply open the forum page press (Ctrl + P) and change the destination to 'download as pdf' and simply download the whole forum page as pdf.